# I have trouble finding out why I got this index out of range error

Tags: python, loops, indexing, error-handling

I was given this code

```
lista = list(range(30))
print(lista)
for i in range(0,len(lista)):
    if lista[i]%3 == 0:
        del lista[i]

print(lista)
```

And in the if I got and error telling me that it's out of range for my list. But if the for loop is in range of the length of this list it makes no sense that the list index for every i is out of range as it can only get list length number of values?

Comment: You should show the error/stacktrace. Also, what research have you done? Hint: what happens if the test passes? What is the length of what you are walking in the loop, and does that ever change? Even some print() debugging would help, but a live REPL would help

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. If you are modifying the size of the list in a for loop and modifying its length, you won't get the result you want.

Say you can delete one element here in your list of size `size`. So all of a sudden `lista[size-1]` doesn't work, but you still are going to try to access it.

That's your error. the range is defined at the beginning of the call, it's not updated after each iteration.

As mauve and Asier ricardo Rafales Vila said, the solution is `lista = [i for i in range(30) if i%3 != 0]`.

Comment: I would recommend doing a list comprehension to solve this: lista = [i for i in range(30) if i%3 != 0]

Comment: yes, that's true, that's how you should indeed write the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by adding the elements that aren't multiples of 3 to a new list 
ex:

```
lista = list(range(30))
print(lista)
new_lst = []
for i in range(0,len(lista)):
    if lista[i]%3 != 0:
        new_lst.append(lista[i])

print(new_lst)
```